# Automate helm chart installation when new Kubernetes namespace is created

Tags: kubernetes, multi-tenant, kubernetes-helm

I'm creating a Multi-Tenancy Kubernetes infrastructure. 
I created a Helm Chart with my app, and now I need automate the helm chart installation when a new namespace is created.

For example,  when the namespace `client1` is create I need to  run `helm install myrepo/myapp --name client1`.

How can i get the new namespace creation event? And the namespace name?

Answer (score 1):

You can either keep running a script which executes `kubectl get namespace` every since a while and compares the current result with the old result. When you find out a new namespace created, you can then execute `helm install myrepo/myapp --name client1`. Or you can run an application in your cluster. What the application does is basically listing all namespaces in the cluster, comparing the current with the cached, if a new namespace found, then call helm client to install your app. For more information, if you are using golang, I would recommend you to use [kubernetes client-go](https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go) to get the list of namespaces in the cluster and you can refer to the open resource project [pipeline](https://github.com/banzaicloud/pipeline/tree/master/helm) for the helm client-go part to install your app.